# Firefox: "Document Expired Error" for POST page

Tags: firefox, caching, post, browser-cache

In Firefox versions 32 and above, I observe that the cache management is not working as expected. If the cache is full it does not cache the latest page and evict the older one.

If i use a http "POST" request page and navigate away from it and if i hit back button, i get : "Document Expired Error".

Is there anything i can do to instruct firefox to cache the page even if its cache is full, probably by sending any meta headers on the page?

Are there any alternatives to get around it?

Comment: How did you deal with it?

Answer (score -3):

I have this problem, too.  If past history with Firefox is an indicator, you will not get the answer you seek.  The answers will range from "It was never supposed to cache those pages, it was broken before and now it works properly" to "It's your fault for wanting Firefox to act as you expect (the way it always has)" to the most recent "If you don't like it get the source code and fix it yourself"

MY solution to the problem is to use Chrome when I need to do that.  Chrome is growing on me

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you prefer one browser over another that's your cup of tea, but it does not help fix any problem.